# insert decimal values of an integer as their ASCII representation into a char vector

Tags: c++, vector, int

I have an `int` and I would like to convert it to a `vector<char>`.

For example:

```
std::vector<char> MyVct;
int i = 2046;
```

So I want a vector of size 4 which will have:

```
MyVct[0] = '2';   
MyVct[1] = '0';   
MyVct[2] = '4';   
MyVct[3] = '6';
```

How can I do it in the most efficent way ?

Comment: Try divide and remainder.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but UGLY way

Comment: Why is MyVect having differnt characters placed at [0]? Don't vectors use popback and pushback?

Comment: Yes, but u can access them. Think about the what I want and not the grammer of the vector, I can use at method if it make a difference for u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
if (n == 0) { MyVct.push_back('0'); }

else { for ( ; n; n /= 10) { MyVct.push_back('0' + (n % 10)); } }

std::reverse(MyVct.begin(), MyVct.end());
```

Comment: @jrok: The OP was changed, but yeah, you have to reverse it I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

One convenient way would be to use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
auto s1 = std::to_string(i);
std::vector<char> vec1(s1.begin(), s1.end());
```

Comment: +1. But you should note somewhere, that `std::to_string` is C++11 feature, AFAIK.

Comment: @maverik: It is indeed. However if I 'm not mistaken the consensus is that unless otherwise specified, plain "c++" means "the current version of the standard".